# Solving integral in heat equation uniqueness energy method proof without identity

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

In looking at a proof of the uniqueness of the heat equation, we evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^Lw_t(x,t)w(x,t)dx.$$ Now the solution uses the identity $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[w(x,t)]^2 = 2w(x,t)_tw(x,t)$$ which implies $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^L\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[w(x,t)]^2 dx = \int_0^Lw(x,t)_tw(x,t)dx \,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ and then the solution proceeds from there. I wondered whether it is possible to solve this integral to get the same result as above $(1)$, if the above identity hadn't come to mind? I have tried using by parts but I don't think this approach works. I suspect the only way to compute this integral is with the approach above, but would be curious whether there are any other ways of seeing this.

Comment: By “to solve this integral” do you mean to prove that the integral is equal to something in closed form? If so, there's generally no way to make it.

Comment: @Saad Would you like to post this as an answer to get the bounty?

Comment: @Saad So to confirm, there's no "algorithmic" way to get this result without the identity in question coming to mind?

Comment: It's rather ambiguous of saying “algorithmic” way to solve it, and since (1) can be simply derived by integrating over the identity above it without deriving what the integral is equal to exactly, this is indeed the fastest approach.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for uniqueness of solution for some problem? Then it would be helpful to state it.

Comment: @Andrew I provided context of where I found the problem, but really I was only interested in whether there was another way to get to the equality (1). I didn't want to evaluate it in closed form or anything like that, I just wanted to know whether there was any standard procedure for arriving at an equality like (1) if you didn't happen to notice the identity above it.

Comment: Well idk, it's a standard thing. But the ideology goes the other way round. Denote 
$$
I(t)=\int_0^L u^2(x,t)\,dx.
$$
If to prove that $I'(t)\equiv0$ then from $I(0)=0$ would mean $I(t)\equiv0$ and the uniqueness follows. and $I'(t)$ is equal to double of the lhs in (1). So no guessing in this approach.

Comment: This is a very weird question. You wish to prove $\int f=\int g$ without using the fact that $f=g$. Why would anyone look for such a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really about the integral, because all you have done to derive (1) is to substitute 
$$
\partial_t(w^2)=2w\partial_tw.
$$
So the question is how one would derive this equation if one does not know this. But it is just the product rule for derivatives.